# php echoing dynamic variable containing quotes

Tags: php

I have a variable $dcomment and need to do the following:

```
echo '<div class="commentBox">' . 
      '<span class="byText">[BY]</span> ' . 
      '<span class="commenterName"><a href=" '.$webLink.' ">'.$dname.'</a></span>' . 
      '&nbsp; [DATE] ' . $dt . '</span>' . '<br>' .
      '[COMMENT] ' . $dcomment .
      $linkdel . '<br />' . 
'</div>';
```

The variables may contain quotes within them, like

```
$dcomment = "Stackoverflow's great"; // containing single quote in it ... etc
```

is there any built-in php function to solve this or how can I do that?

Comment: I don't see your problem here. What isn't working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: Quotes (in this case double quotes) could break his `href`

Comment: guys, though its a server side scripting, but for you all to review what I was doing, can you please check this code in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ovuwod/2/edit

Comment: the all data if first submitted, stored in mysql database and immediately read and display on the page. Its works fine is there is no escape characters in the input form field but once there is one, it does not work. That's the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did this and worked: [I have voted up everyone who helped me here, thank you all]

```
$name= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$emailAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailAddress']);
$webAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['webAddress']);
$comment=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$submit=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']);
```

Thanks to @MightyPork :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **[`htmlentities($str)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)** (click for manual page)

It will replace all applicable characters to HTML entities, so you don't have to fear getting `"`, `<` and similar characters in your mark-up and attribute fields.

---

If you want to also escape single quotes `'`, use

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)
```

(as described in the documentation)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ovuwod/2/edit : can you please check this code, though its a server side language, I put in jsbin for you to view the code

Comment: Nope, it's **not** correct. (1) You should sanitize your database input at the top - use `mysql_real_escape_string` on all of the `$_POST` fields you are going to stuff into database. (2) Use `htmlentities` only on your php strings, not the html code. Like this: `...<div>" . htmlentities($divtext) . "</div>...` and `<a href= '" . htmlentities($myUrl, ENT_QUOTES) . "'>...`

Comment: why not correct? I guess the issue is in INSERT INTO ... VALUES statement, can you please guide me to fix it.

Comment: ahh ... looks great for me, let me try that

Comment: worked with mysql_real_escape_string(); ... dont's have much exp on php/DB ... now issue is fixed, thanks ... gonna accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all quotes with their HTML entity. `htmlentities` or `str_replace`

`htmlentities`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

`str_replace`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

**Note**: You need to use `ENT_QUOTES` for `htmlentities`.

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlentities($dcomment, ENT_QOUTES)
```

Comment: htmlentities was used on the entire div in the given jsbin.. just showing an example.

Answer (score 1):

To escape strings for use in HTML context, PHP provides the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function. It will replace `"`, `'`, `&`, `<`, and `>` with their respective HTML entities.

If you need to escape strings for use as an URL, there's the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlenodce) functions.

Sometimes it's necessary to combine both, i.e. html-escape an urlencoded string.